# Php update table and order field after INSERT

Tags: php, sql

I have a table on sql that I update through a simple php form. The table is formed by 5 field:

`-id (primary key)`

`-data ("Y-m-d")`

`-value1 (Varchar(10))`

`-value2 (Varchar(10))`

`-ID_PERSONAL (int(11))`

Suppose I insert in the table a row like this:

`("",2019-01-01,"A","B","")`

`("",2019-01-03,"C","D","")`

`("",2019-01-02,"E","F","")`

It will assign to the second filed the ID n.2 and to third ID n.2. So I put also the field ID_PERSONAL where I'd like to have the exact order based on data of the event.

So this is the result I'd like to have after the record are uploaded:

`("",2019-01-01,"A","B","1")`

`("",2019-01-03,"C","D","2")`

`("",2019-01-02,"E","F","3")`

what i'm looking for is a function that update in the correct way the table after INSERT

Comment: Hi, why don't you use an AUTO_INCREMENT?

Comment: i id IS PRIMARY KEY AND AUTOINCREMENT TOO...i FORGOT TO WRITE IT:-)

Comment: So an auto increment does what you want, it increases the number automatically as the lines are inserted in the table, so the ID_PERSONAL is useless simply use the id column as the order

Comment: OK BUT SOMETIMES i INSERT BEFORE THE RECORD OF 2019-01-02 AND AFTER THE RECORD OF SOME DAYS BEFORE (FOR EXAMPE 2018-12-01)

Comment: So you would like to order by data column (the date)?

Comment: it is a commercial program in which invoices are entered and sometimes they are in order of date sometimes they arrive late ... for this I wanted a field that was automatically updated based on the date of the document

Comment: Look in my opinion, you can insert the lines in the table at random date order, and in the `SELECT` SQL statements you simply use `ORDER BY data`

Comment: This is why there is an `order by` functionality.

Comment: You are using RDBMS incorrectly if you are worried about the order in which the data is displayed inside the DB.  However, you can create a unique ID by combining the auto increment ID with a timestamp.  :)

Comment: thanks a lot!useful